# How to get database tables list from MySQL (SHOW TABLES)

Tags: mysql, go

I have a problem with getting database table list (SHOW TABLES) in Go.

I use this packages

> database/sql
>
> gopkg.in/gorp.v1
>
> github.com/ziutek/mymysql/godrv

and connect to MYSQL by this code:

```
db, err := sql.Open(
    "mymysql",
    "tcp:127.0.0.1:3306*test/root/root")
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

dbmap := &DbMap{Conn:&gorp.DbMap{Db: db}}
```

And I use this code to get list of tables

```
result, _ := dbmap.Exec("SHOW TABLES")
```

But result is empty!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm trying this code and work successfully. I create a list of string and use Select query to get list of database tables.

```
tables := []string{}
dbmap.Select(&tables, "SHOW TABLES")
fmt.Println(tables)
```

Answer (score 10):

I use classic [go-sql-driver/mysql](https://godoc.org/github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql):

```
db, _ := sql.Open("mysql", "root:qwerty@/dbname")

res, _ := db.Query("SHOW TABLES")

var table string

for res.Next() {
    res.Scan(&table)
    fmt.Println(table)
}
```

PS don't ignore errors! This is only an example

Answer (score -1):

To anyone in the future, I'm achive my goal using DB.Migrator().GetTables()